# Wordpress button customization

Tags: wordpress

How can I edit this button, so that the text is shorter in the mobile version?

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary standard-button" type="button">
  <span class="screen-reader-text">
    Ribbon button label:Simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
  </span>
  simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
</button>
```

In the mobile version I want something like:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary standard-button" type="button">
  <span class="screen-reader-text">
    Ribbon button label:Simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
  </span>
  simply dummy
</button>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Use JS or jQuery to change the button label.

Answer (score 0):

You can change button label using jquery like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  btnResize(768 /* Mobile Viewport width */ );

  /* change button label on resize */
  $(window).resize(function() {
    btnResize(768);
  })
})

function btnResize(width) {
  if ($(window).width() < width) {
    // For button or any other html tag
    $("#ribbon-btn1").html('simply dummy');
    // for input button 
    $("#ribbon-btn2").attr('value', 'simply dummy');
  } else {
    // For button tag
    $("#ribbon-btn1").html('Simply dummy text of the printing and typesettingsimply dummy text of the printing and typesetting');
    // for input button 
    $("#ribbon-btn2").attr('value', 'Simply dummy text of the printing and typesettingsimply dummy text of the printing and typesetting');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ribbon-btn1">
        Simply dummy text of the printing and typesettingsimply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    </button>
<input type="button" value="Simply dummy text of the printing and typesettingsimply dummy text of the printing and typesetting" id="ribbon-btn2">
```